# Unable to connect to socket on client side

Tags: node.js, laravel, websocket, redis, socket.io

I'm using Laravel 5.4, VirtualBox, and Homestead. I want to be able to send out broadcasts every time a new user is created, however when I goto my test it doesn't update the `power` but my node instance logs this

```
Message Recieved: {"event":"App\\Events\\EventName","data":{"data":{"power":"10"},"socket":null},"socket":null}
```

which I'm assuming it means it works. What I am doing wrong?

api.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    // this doesn't do anything other than to
    // tell you to go to /fire
    return "go to /fire";
});

Route::get('fire', function () {
    // this fires the event
    event(new App\Events\EventName());
    return "event fired";
});

Route::get('test', function () {
    // this checks for the event
    return view('test');
});
```

socket.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

EventName

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class EventName implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


    public $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = array(
            'power'=> '10'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
/*        return new PrivateChannel('test-channel');*/
            return ['test-channel'];

    }
}
```

master.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FiveOne Socket.io</title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
@yield('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

test.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <p id="power">0</p>
@stop

@section('footer')
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>

    <script>
        //var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        //var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');
        var socket = io(window.location.origin + ':3000');
        socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function(message){
            // increase the power everytime we load test route
            $('#power').text(parseInt($('#power').text()) + parseInt(message.data.power));
        });
    </script>
@stop
```

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=192.168.10.10
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

redis.conf

```
bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.10.10
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "ioredis": "^3.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "ioredis": "^3.1.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

**Edit:** I just tried to log the socket connection and its returning false. I'm thinking this is a problem with homestead but i'm not sure

```
<script>
   var socket = io('http://192.168.10.10:3000');
   console.log(socket.connected);
    //alert(window.location.origin + ':3000');
    socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function(message){
        // increase the power everytime we load test route
        $('#power').text(parseInt($('#power').text()) + parseInt(message.data.power));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you solved ?